# Four matchsticks puzzle

Tags: matches

Take 4 matchsticks and set them out in this pattern:

> VII

In mathematics this is 7 in Roman numerals. Now move just a single matchstick and the answer should be 1 (one).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You

> move the right-most matchstick to go *above* the others and horizontal,

so that

> the matches spell out $\sqrt{1}$, which is of course 1.

Like this:

> [image: moving matches]

Comment: This is only the correct answer if you focus on the positive side of life.

Answer (score 41):

Move

> one of the I's to the beginning

like so:

> I V I which in logic and proper numerals is 1 or 1

giving

> the answer true

which is

> binary value of 1

Answer (score 18):

> Turn the V into an X (XII). In [Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) this is '* 1 1' = 1.

Comment: That's very creative

Comment: This is a [different kind](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/54391/5373) of Polishing.

Answer (score 13):

I'd say you can

> strike through the `V` with an `I`, so that the `V` is a mistake! This gives `VI` which is one.

I kept thinking that the answer must be in Roman numerals and thus came up with this.

Answer (score 10):

You

> take the right-most matchstick, and polish it until it has a mirror-like sheen, then place it above the others and look at it at from a very low viewpoint, so that the matchsticks and their reflection look

like this:

> /\ |
>     \/ |

which reads

> 01

PS

> Best of luck with the polishing ;)

Comment: Ho ho ho, very smart

Answer (score 8):

Other answers are really so weird... Should not it be like this:

> Move the first match below the two last matches
>  /||
>   |

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE. This is a very good first try :)

Answer (score 3):

> Moving the last match to the first position makes: IVI. This is the roman numeral for **one** thousand (since the question didn't specify one *of what*).